# Update rows having same id and name

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here is Table t1

```
id name amount close
1  jon   4000    0
1  jon   5000    0
1  jon   9000    0
```

i want sum of amount at the end of close column

```
id name amount close
1  jon   4000    0
1  jon   5000    0
1  jon   9000  18000
```

I'm try to update close

```
update t1 set close = (select sum(amount) from t1  where id = '1' group by id)
```

but this query update all row of close like this

```
id name amount close
1  jon   4000  18000  
1  jon   5000  18000
1  jon   9000  18000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
update t1
    set close = (select sum(t11.amount)
                 from t1 t11
                 where t1.id = t11.id
                );
```

However, this will still update all the rows.  You just want the last one.  Well, in SQL, rows are unordered, but SQLite offers `rowid`.  This allows you to do:

```
update t1
    set close = (select sum(t11.amount)
                 from t1 t11
                 where t1.id = t11.id
                )
    where rowid = (select max(rowid)
                   from t1 t11
                   where t1.id = t11.id
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
Update [Temp_Table]
      set [Temp_Table].[close] = (Select sum(amount) from [Temp_Table]  where id=1 group by ID)
      where amount = (Select max(amount) from [Temp_Table] group by id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
UPDATE testing1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(amount) maxi, 
            SUM(amount) tot FROM testing1) b ON b.maxi = a.amount
SET a.close = b.tot
```